# Excel to generate a list of test cases from a list of options

Tags: microsoft-excel

I appreciate any help on this... Say I have 5 options/features:

```
F1
F2
F3
F4
F5
```

Each of which can be on or off (1 | 0)

How in Excel would I display all the options?  The order doesn't matter and I don't want duplicates.

The first test would be:

```
F1-1, F2-1, F3-1, F4-1, F5-1     I.e. All options are on.
F1-1, F2-0, F3-1, F4-1, F5-1     I.e. Option 2 is disabled. 
F1-1, F2-1, F3-0, F4-1, F5-1     I.e. Option 3 is disabled. 
Etc... to cover all combinations of the features being on or off.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a **binary counter**:

In **A1** enter:

```
=DEC2BIN(ROW()-1,5)
```

and copy down:

[image]

To get a better format, in **B1** enter:

```
="F1-" & MID(A1,1,1) & ",F2-" & MID(A1,2,1) & ",F3-" & MID(A1,3,1) & ",F4-" & MID(A1,4,1) & ",F5-" & MID(A1,5,1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can manually calculate the (reversed) **binary digit**:

In **A1** enter:

```
=MOD(QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,POWER(2,COLUMN()-1)), 2)
```

Copy across the number of options/features, then down.

[image]

Comment: Credit to Gary's Student for first answer to suggest binary counter. I've formatted my answer similarly to his for consistency.

Comment: I think your approach is really cool! *(+1)*